# Two processes under one GUI window

Tags: c++, qt, process, juce

Is it possible to have two processes running under one GUI window?
I have two apps, one built with Qt, one built with [JUCE framework](https://juce.com/) and I would like to run them both under one front end Window. It should work on Windows & Mac and hopefully also Linux.

Here is how I imagine the 2 processes are shown in the main window. For process A & B:

1. A is initially running and visible in the main GUI window.
2. A creates process B, B is now active and A is suspended. B is shown in the main window and A is hidden.

I'm writing it using C++. So any suggestions where to look into would be very appreciated.

Comment: With Qt you can embed a GUI application inside a different application. I know there are other technologies that do the same.

Comment: You said you are using `c++` however standard c++ has no concept of a window, GUI or process. So you should be more specific. I would guess you mean `winapi` but it should be mentioned in the tags if this is correct.

Comment: Windows and Linux have different answers to this question and I have no idea about Mac OS X.

Comment: Assuming it's Windows, look into OLE in-place activation. That sounds like what you need. Even with that, though, the server application's relationship with the window is not as straightforward as that of the container application.

Comment: At least on Windows, a window is owned by the thread that creates it, and only that thread can service that window.  But, it is possible to join multiple windows from different threads/processes together in a parent/child relationship, but [you have to careful doing so](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683).

Comment: @drescherjm the two process are built with QT and JUCE frameworks.